# How to get the ItemId of a forwarded email in ExchangeWebServices Managed API

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS Managed API to find an EmailItem and forward it to another recipient. I want to record the ItemId of the **forwarded** email, but I can't figure out how to find this property.

```
var originalMail = EmailMessage.Bind(exchangeService, originalMailId);
var fwdMessage = originalMail.CreateForward();

fwdMessage.ToRecipients.Add("foo@bar.com");
fwdMessage.BodyPrefix = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, html);
fwdMessage.Subject = "Testing 123";

// Send the message
fwdMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

How can I get the ItemId of the `fwdMessage` email?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `ResponseMessage` object doesn't expose an ID. You could try stamping a GUID in a custom extended property before sending, then searching Sent Items for the item that has that GUID.